# Macro written in English working for Japan users but not for French users

Tags: excel, vba, sap-analysis-for-office

The business has BPC 11.1 version and using analysis for Office Excel AFO, but they are facing one issue that is when business users are trying to execute the macro, their system is not able to read that macro. It is because their system Office language is French or maybe Spanish or Italian, but our

The macro written in English should work for French users like it worked for Japan users. In the system of French people, the system is not able to read macro logic in English.
But when it was in Japan, the system was able to read the same macro in english.

The logic is not readable for French users :

```
Result = Application.Run("SAPGetProperty", "IsConnected", "DS_1")
```

Comment: "...their system is not able to read that macro." do you mean they cannot open the file with the macro or is there an error of some sort when trying to run the macro? If the latter, what is the error (i assume the single line of code you posted throws said error?)

Comment: If you talk them through opening the VBA page containing that code what do they see? I can well believe that Japanese uses approximately the same English words for most Excel actions but I wouldn't be too surprised if the French language police haven't insisted that all actions are described in French. Software is Logiciel there.